How do I create three curved boards on the back part of the chair?
How do I create three curved boards on the back part of the chair?


Hello and welcome, can you elaborate more. For me it looks like 3 rectangles that can be easily add to your scene and adjust the height and thickness

Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

The trick to getting this slight curve might be proportional editing.  Those parts are called rails.


Add edge loops to the back posts ( hover over geometry and press control + r and roll the middle mouse button)

Delete the faces where you want the top and cross rails (3 curve parts) of the chair.




Bridge the edge loops to create the rails.  Press F3 to search 'Bridge Edge Loops'.



Add edge loops to the rails ( hover over geometry and press control + r and roll the middle mouse button)

5.turn on proportional editing at the very top of the Blender interface(shortcut: O) and switch it to 'Sphere'


Select the middle edge loops of the chair and drag them until you get a nice curve. Lock it to an axis. (G + X,Y or Z)


You can change the size of the sphere by rolling the middle mouse after making a selection.

Thank you so much man. Very detailed explanation. I didn't get the second step tho. and my chair looks kinda weird atm. like the middle tile under the 3d parts gets curved with it and it feels like the middle 4 edge that I selected and moved are mostly being curved rather than all the other parts curving smoothly. I did make sure to enable proportional editing tho

I think I understand.  When you add edge loops you have to be careful to make everything symmetrical.  You have to watch carefully that everything will line up when you go to step 2.

Also, I would say I am missing one thing in the final step, number 6.  When you select a part of the geometry, you can press G + X, Y or Z to lock your translation along an axis.

Yeh I did lock it to a specific axis. I still don't understand step 2 tho. Everything is symmetrical since I didn't really change the location of the loop cuts.

You can see from the diagram, I added a couple of vertical loop cuts to the back posts, maybe that is what you are noticing so that the rails would sit more in the middle.  It wasn't necessary, but I thought it looked better.

Hmm okay. But still your curve is much more smooth than what mine turns out. Any idea how to fix that? mine feels like only the middle part is being curved

Add loopcuts to the rails.  Also, if you follow this technique, you can apply modifiers to the finished chair, bevel and subdivision, to slightly round all the edges.

I have updated the images.

To do the rails? The 3 curved? I did add loop cuts but it doesn't look good. lemme send you a picture. https://postimg.cc/z3JV1BsZ check this link out

Patience, you've almost got it.  Use your mouse wheel to adjust the area affected by the proportional editing and make it slightly larger.  If you have another question, it should be a new question.

(Also, I noted that you did not switch proportional editing  to "sphere" in the image.)
